# Why chiral Majorana fermions with finite momentum are called as an Majorana fermion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, majorana-fermions

For a $p_x+ip_y$ superconductor, at its boundary there will be an edge state
$$
\gamma_{p} = \alpha_pc_p  + \alpha_{-p}^*c_{-p}^\dagger,
$$
where $c_p$ is an ordinary fermion operator and $p$ denotes the momentum. It has chirality with the dispersion relation $E_p = v_Fp$ and satisfies the relation $\gamma_{p}^\dagger = \gamma_{-p}$.

This edge state is usually called as a chiral Majorana fermion. However, a Majorana fermion must equal to its Hermitian $\gamma^\dagger = \gamma$ in my understanding.

Why $\gamma_p$ is considered or called as a Majorana fermion here?

Comment: $\gamma(x)^\dagger=\gamma(x)\Rightarrow\gamma(p)^\dagger=\gamma(-p)$...

Comment: So people call $\gamma(p)$ a Majorana fermion because $\gamma(x) = \int dp e^{ip x} \gamma(p)$ is a Majorana fermion. So is there an original paper mention it ? Just curious about it.